# How to preserve Google Cloud Storage rows order in compressed files

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We've created a query in BigQuery that returns SKUs and correlations between them. Something like:

```
sku_0,sku_1,0.023
sku_0,sku_2,0.482
sku_0,sku_3,0.328
sku_1,sku_0,0.023
sku_1,sku_2,0.848
sku_1,sku_3,0.736
```

The result has millions of rows and we export it to Google Cloud Storage which results in several compressed files.

These files are downloaded and we have a Python application that loops through them to make some calculations using the correlations.

We tried then to make use of the fact that our first columns of SKUs is already ordered and not have to apply this ordering inside of our application.

But then we just found that the files we get from GCS changes the order in which the skus appear.

It looks like the files are created by several processes reading the results and saving it in different files, which breaks the ordering we wanted to maintain.

As an example, if we have 2 files created, the first file would look something like that:

```
sku_0,sku_1,0.023
sku_0,sku_3,0.328
sku_1,sku_2,0.0848
```

And the second file:

```
sku_0,sku_2,0.482
sku_1,sku_0,0.328
sku_1,sku_3,0.736
```

This is an example of what it looks like two processes reading the results and each one saving its current row on a specific file which changes the order of the column.

So we looked for some flag that we could use to force the preservation of the ordering but couldn't find any so far.

Is there some way we could use to force the order in these GCS files to be preserved? Or is there some workaround?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know there is no flag to maintain order.

As a workaround you can rethink your data output to use of `NESTED` type, and make sure that what you want to group together are converted in `NESTED` rows, and you can export to JSON.

Comment: we just migrated to standard sql and this worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> is there some workaround?

As an option - you can move your processing logic from Python to BigQuery, thus eliminating moving data out of BigQuery to GCS.